# SQL query with condition when one field not equal to another

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have fields:  id | content | updateTime | creationTime

When insertion done both updateTime and creationTime get filled with current time. On update only updateTime field get changed. When I need to find all data created on '2012-06-28' I simply use:

```
SELECT id, content FROM tbl WHERE creationTime LIKE '2012-06-28%'`
```

But to get all data that was updated excluding created data I need to use something like this:

```
SELECT id, content FROM tbl WHERE creationTime LIKE '2012-06-28%' AND creationTime != updateTime
```

This can't work, obviously. Though I could find all updated data by comparing values of two 'time' collumns inside php, I'd still love to do it inside query.

UPD: Well, it turns out that I was absolutely unaware that sql allows not only compare value of a field with a given variable, number... but also it can compare value of one field with another.

Comment: is that created on the 28th and edited on the 28th but not at the same time as it was created? Wouldnt it be better keeping the updateTime null until there has been an update?

Comment: Why do you say "*This can't work, obviously*"?  I think it should, although I agree with @marabutt that having `updateTime=NULL` would perhaps be more semantically correct.  (As an aside, to match on date you will find that `DATE(creationTime) = '2012-06-28'` will be more efficient than your string pattern matching approach).

Comment: @marabutt - INSERT happens only once for each row, UPDATE can happen many times. So I just use `updateTime` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - this way `updateTime` gets updated automatically by DB itself. I just need to remember to insert date when record is being created.

Comment: @eggyal - you're right. Post updated.

Answer (score 8):

Use `<>` instead `!=` (that isn't compatible with some DMBS)

So

```
SELECT id, content 
FROM tbl 
WHERE creationTime LIKE '2012-06-28%' AND creationTime <> updateTime
```

If you want some documentation [you can find here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

However, your query have to work properly with `!=`

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc : take a look to the tags that he used

Comment: Sorry never used mySQL myself, just PostgreSQL, how did you know? :)

Comment: The documentation to which you link suggests that both `<>` and `!=` are valid inequality operators.  Why would your proposed change make any difference?

Comment: @eggyal They are the same, but `!=` is supported only by some DMBS so, if you have to "export" that query in a different "language", you have to modify it

Comment: @eggyal It was just a suggestion

Answer (score 3):

**Your query is correct (on mySQL¹), don't know why would you think otherwise**

¹ `<>` is the SQL operator for not equal. Some implementations of it (PostgreSQL or MySQL for instance), however, accept `!=` too. It is a good practice to always use `<>` to avoid problems if you ever use your code on a different database.

Comment: Doesn't MySQL support both forms for the inequality operator?

Comment: There's a difference between the SQL specification and the implementations that exists nowadays. MySQL might support things that aren't on the specification but that won't work on other SQL compilant databases.

Comment: Agreed, but given that this question was tagged [tag:mysql], how does this answer the OP's question?

Answer (score 1):

Only change the not operator from `!=` to `<>`

```
SELECT id, content FROM tbl WHERE creationTime LIKE '2012-06-28%' AND creationTime <> updateTime
```

Comment: Doesn't MySQL support both forms for the inequality operator?